# unable to print selenium drop down list

Tags: selenium

The code below is not working to print the dropdown list

```
public class listAssignment {

    public void assigntest(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
                "C:/Users/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64/geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        WebElement month_dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("month"));

        List<WebElement> options = month_dropdown.findElements(By.id("month"));

        for (WebElement option : options) {
            String month_name = option.getText();
          System.out.println("output====="+month_name );
        }
```

Comment: Your code seem to be incomplete...

Comment: **What** is not working? Please read [ask], and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should almost work. Here is a version which I have tested with python

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
driver.maximize_window()

WebElement_month_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_id('month').text.splitlines()
print(WebElement_month_dropdown)

for month in WebElement_month_dropdown:
    print ("output=====" + month)
```

Answer (score 0):

Added select class (Select month = new Select(month_dropdown), and its working fine now Thanks..